# Запуск minecraft 1.12.2 через bat

Tags: minecraft, launcher

Я пишу лаунчер на java. Но, опять столкнулся с проблемой : как запускать версии minecraft через bat?

Прошерстил интернет вдоль и поперёк, но нигде нет точного ответа.

Запустив TLauncher я получил полную команду запуска minecraft:

`` C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\javaw.exe -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dos.name=Windows 10 -Dos.version=10.0 -Xmn128M -Xmx11568M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\versions\1.12.2\natives -cp C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\tlauncher\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.22\realms-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified) -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username JK_DragonLoading --version 1.12.2 --gameDir C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified) --assetsDir C:\Users\zucho\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --accessToken null --userType legacy --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 ``

Но, если эту команду целиком вставить в bat файл, то он запускается и моментально закрывается и ничего больше не происходит.

Я даже декомпилил сам TLauncher, но конкретного кода, который запускает minecraft нету, либо я его не заметил.

Comment: Вот есть опенсорсный рабочий лаунчер (или по крайней мере год назад, когда я последний раз запускал майнкрафт, он был рабочим), посмотри в нём: https://github.com/Kron4ek/minecraft-vortex-launcher

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf То что надо! Буду разбираться, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Убери "-Dos.name=Windows 10" из команды. (Консоль некорректно обрабатывает пробел)
- Замени "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\javaw.exe" на
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe".
- Во всех других аргументах заключи значения в "кавычки" если в них есть пробелы и \ замени на \\

---

```
'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_281\\bin\\java.exe'
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dos.version=10.0 -Xmn128M
 -Xmx11568M -Djava.library.path="C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\versions\\1.12.2\\natives"
 -cp "C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\tlauncher\\patchy\\1.1\\patchy-1.1.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\oshi-project\\oshi-core\\1.1\\oshi-core-1.1.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\net\\java\\dev\\jna\\jna\\4.4.0\\jna-4.4.0.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\net\\java\\dev\\jna\\platform\\3.4.0\\platform-3.4.0.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\ibm\\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\\51.2\\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\net\\sf\\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\\5.0.3\\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecjorbis\\20101023\\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecwav\\20101023\\codecwav-20101023.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\\20101123\\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\\20100824\\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\soundsystem\\20120107\\soundsystem-20120107.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\io\\netty\\netty-all\\4.1.9.Final\\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\21.0\\guava-21.0.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.5\\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.5\\commons-io-2.5.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\commons-codec\\commons-codec\\1.10\\commons-codec-1.10.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\net\\java\\jutils\\jutils\\1.0.0\\jutils-1.0.0.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.8.0\\gson-2.8.0.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\authlib\\1.5.25\\authlib-1.5.25.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\realms\\1.10.22\\realms-1.10.22.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-compress\\1.8.1\\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpclient\\4.3.3\\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\commons-logging\\commons-logging\\1.1.3\\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpcore\\4.3.2\\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\it\\unimi\\dsi\\fastutil\\7.1.0\\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.8.1\\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.8.1\\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\text2speech\\1.10.3\\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;
C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\versions\\1.12.2\\1.12.2.jar"
 -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory="C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)"
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
 -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true
 -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true net.minecraft.client.main.Main
 --username JK_DragonLoading
 --version 1.12.2
 --gameDir "C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)"
 --assetsDir "C:\\Users\\zucho\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\SimpleMinecraft(ZuchoK`S modified)\\assets"
 --assetIndex 1.12
 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 --accessToken null
 --userType legacy
 --versionType release
 --width 925
 --height 530
```

Comment: Консоль ругается на "не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

Comment: В общем. В консоли некорректно распознаются пробелы в аргументах. Если значения аргументов, в которых есть пробелы заключить в "Кавычки" появляется проблема, связанная со знаком \, который обычно используется в комбинации с другими символами (к примеру \n для обозначения новой строки).
Если консоль ругается на "не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.", то скорее всего java.exe отсутствует в папке C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\. В этом случае стоит сверить местонахождение java.exe и, если в пути есть пробелы, тоже заключить в "кавычки".

Comment: Просто все проблемы возникают из-за пробелов в путях.

Comment: Путь к java.exe правильный, ибо в консоли после "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_291\\bin\\java.exe"  появляются команды именно для java, но, не смотря на это, консоль всё равно ругается как на команды, так и на путь.

Comment: Ну... На форуме я ничем больше помочь не могу. Извини.