# Запуск Minecraft C#

Tags: c#, bat, minecraft

Я новичок в c# и хочу создать лаунчер для сервера Minecraft.
Вообщем, как правильно запустить Minecraft 1.12.2, пиратка ( с OptiFine )?
Можно поподробнее описать все теги запуска?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что Ваш вопрос сводится к "с какой консольной командой надо в программе на C# вызвать `Process.Start()`? А это - уже к знатокам майнкрафта...

Comment: Пробовал? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-username-and-password-as-prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего использовать библиотеку, например https://github.com/CmlLib/CmlLib.Core в ней есть всё для запуска игры. Без библиотеки это достаточно сложная задача, нужно составить огромную сторку с аргументами для запуска, и эта строка будет выглядить примерно так же как тут [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250360/Запуск-minecraft-1-12-2-через-bat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250360/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-minecraft-1-12-2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-bat)
Если в двух словах, нужно спарсить json в папке с версией, в нём указана вся информация для запуска, и из этой информации можно составить подобную строку с аргрументами